# Finding a common node with key between two different BinarySearchTrees

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am currently trying to write methods that checks all the nodes in two different Binary Search trees and find nodes with common keys between the two trees. (i.e. trying to find a node from tree 1 and a node from tree 2 that contains the same keys. If a common node is found, the method returns true, otherwise it returns false. The second tree is stored in a different object than tree 1, called `GraphicalObject`. And the key is in the form of coordinates and size comparason is done using column order.

I have written the following code, but wondering if there is anything wrong with it or if there is anything I could improve up on?

1) A method that checks if a node from tree 1 is the same as every node in tree 2 using recursive calls. the `compareTo` method is defined else where.

```
public boolean findPixel(BinaryNode node1, BinaryNode node2, GraphicalObject gobj) {
    //Creating the final coordinate key by altering the original key in nodes of tree 2.
    int xCor = node2.getData().getLocation().xCoord() + gobj.getOffset().xCoord() - graphicPos.xCoord();
    int yCor = node2.getData().getLocation().yCoord() + gobj.getOffset().yCoord() - graphicPos.yCoord();
    Location newLoc = new Location(xCor, yCor); //Creates the final key to be checked up on
    if(node1.getData().getLocation().compareTo(newLoc) == 0) { //If keys are the same
        return true;
    } else {
        if(node1.getData().getLocation().compareTo(newLoc) == -1) { //if key from node 1 is smaller than key from node 2.
            node2 = node2.getLeft();
            findPixel(node1, node2, gobj);
        } else {
            node2 = node2.getRight();
            findPixel(node1, node2, gobj);
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

2) A method that uses `findPixel` method to check every node in tree 1 and compare them to every node in tree 2, using inorder traversal.

```
private boolean findCommonNode(BinaryNode node1, BinaryNode node2, GraphicalObject gobj) {
    if(node1 != null) {
        findCommonNode(node1.getLeft(), node2, gobj);
        return findPixel(node1, node2, gobj);
        findCommonNode(node1.getRight(), node2, gobj);
    }
}
```

3) method that returns true if common node between the two trees is found, or false otherwise.

```
public boolean intersects(GraphicalObject gobj){
    BinaryNode tempNode = newTree.getRoot();
    BinaryNode tempNode2 = gobj.getTree().getRoot();
    if (findCommonNode(tempNode, tempNode2, gobj) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? Or is there anything I could do to make it better or run more efficiently?

Comment: maybe you want to do `return findPixel(node1, node2, gobj);` // etc

Comment: Do you mean in the first method with in the else and if statements? :)
Also, in the second method with the in-order traversal, is the return statement okay to be put there? I wasn't sure if that would work.

Comment: Sorry I was talking about the first method (I got bored reading) - try it and see if it works

Comment: I think it works a bit. This is actually a part of an class assignment to make a game where if a common node is found, two graphics icons on screen will overlap each other, which is not what we want. Right now, it some times will not overlap (which is good), but a lot of the times, it still overlaps even though there are no common nodes (meaning the methods didn't detect common nodes properly). I am not sure what is wrong, I went through the code step by step to figure out how it works, and it seems fine?  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things that seem wrong in your code:

In the first method you calling recursive call to `findPixel` - you need to return the answer of the method back. It should be like this:

```
} else {
    if(node1.getData().getLocation().compareTo(newLoc) == -1) 
        return findPixel(node1, node2.getLeft(), gobj);
    else
        return findPixel(node1, node2.getRight(), gobj);
}
return false;
```

You should also add check for `null` for `node2` before extract the location. Add this to the first line of `findPixel` function:

```
if (node2 == null)
    return false;
```

On your second method, you using return statement inside the function -> therefor you will not get inorder traversal but it will ignore the right side of the tree. That code need to be as follow:

```
if(node1 != null) {
    return (findCommonNode(node1.getLeft(), node2, gobj)) ||  (findPixel(node1, node2, gobj)) || (findCommonNode(node1.getRight(), node2, gobj));
}
```

This way you can save some running time (if the answer is true no need to continue looking for more similar nodes).

Last, third method can be modify to (readability):

```
BinaryNode tempNode = newTree.getRoot();
BinaryNode tempNode2 = gobj.getTree().getRoot();
return (findCommonNode(tempNode, tempNode2, gobj));
```

This for your given code.

However, more optimize solution will be to traverse on one tree and insert there value (after hash) in hash-map - then traverse on the second tree and for each node: check if he exist in the hash-map. this will be `O(n)` complexity in contrast to your solution which is `O(n^2)`.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I made the adjustments as you suggested and it seems to be working properly now! (I will also try the hash table method). Thanks again. ^^